# Adding pin on mapView is not working on appstore version

Tags: ios, android-mapview, nsurlconnection

I have submitted my app and been accepted couple of weeks ago. However, I have an issue that one of my critical functionality which is adding pin is not working but it works in building version. Adding pin requires URL connection. Could you please look at the answer that I get from apple developer and guide me please?

It shouldn't be causing your problem (at least not directly), but in general
having networking code like this live inside your UI code is very problematic
for a number of reasons:

-On general architecture grounds, it's a large violation of the MVC (model
view controller) architecture.  The pin annotation is obviously heavily tied
to your UI (the view), while networking is clearly part of your backend (the
model).

-Because iOS REQUIRES the main thread to remain responsive, attaching code
that does IO or computation to the main thread is inherently risky.  It can be
done and work well, but doing it incorrectly will inevitably lead to crashes.

Comment: if you would share some code, that might help you get some answers and more feedback. it's nearly impossible to make suggestions blindly.

Comment: When you say that it is not working in production, but is working in the building version, I assume that means when it is compiled in debug  mode. Does it work on both the simulator and an actual device? Several things that work on the simulator can work differently when testing on an actual device (such as performance).

Answer (score 0):

NSURLConnection works in background and interactions with UI should go on main thread.

So, if you add your pin at the connectionDidFinish method for example, you should do like this:

```
[mapView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addAnnotation:) withObject:yourAnnotation waitUntilDone:[[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]];
```

Hope that helps you. I wrote from windows but the line should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure about what you are trying to achieve. Are App folks complaining because you are fetching URL directly in the Main thread ? Could you just send a code snippet showing how you fetch urls ?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to drop the pin (not tied to URL connection at all) and once the pin drops, load your data for the callout or annotation (which is what I'm assuming you are doing). You can always put a loading indicator or progressHUD up to tell the user they need to wait for something. It isn't exactly ideal, but in instances where you need to wait for data, what are you going to do?

Apple really doesn't care about blocking the UI so long as the user is aware you are blocking it. Like a progress bar or progress HUD. The user can see the app is still working and doing something. Not showing anything and having the UI just freeze while it waits for the main thread/main loop to return isn't going to work. It is just bad design and Apple will likely ding you for it.